# Get XML content of GDAL VRT memory datasource in Python

Tags: gdal, vrt, memory-layer

I'm trying to fetch the XML content of a GDAL Memory VRT raster datasource in Python without saving the datasource to disk. I looked into the GDAL Python API, but have absolutely no idea how to get the VRT XML string.

```py
from osgeo import gdal
ds = gdal.Translate('/vsimem/temp.vrt','C:/Data/myraster.tif','-of VRT')
vrtXmlString = ds.????
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, once again I was too quick with the question. I have just found the answer on the Internet (https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/6767). Maybe someone could use it.

```py
from osgeo import gdal
ds = gdal.Translate('/vsimem/temp.vrt','C:/Data/myraster.tif','-of VRT')
vrtXmlString = ds.GetMetadata('xml:VRT')[0]
```